# Display entire row in last

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know this question already asked or not but i have not found anywhere. Please I am not on advanced level SQL so apologies if this is too easy!!

We have a table for student in where the students enrolled in different courses. What i want is to make a query in such a way that the entire row of student name and selected course like Mathematics and Gym show in last. Table is below in the picture.

[image]

I have tried this but it only shows the course in descending order. Any help or an idea would be appreciated!

```
SELECT *
FROM student_birthday
WHERE student_fullname = 'Alpha'
ORDER BY student_course DESC, student_fullname;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use booleans for a single value:

```
SELECT sb.*
FROM student_birthday sb
WHERE sb.student_fullname = 'Alpha'
ORDER BY (student_course = 'Gym');
```

If you want more control over the ordering, then you might use a `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY (case when student_course = 'Mathematics' then 1
               when student_course = 'Gym' then 3
               else 2
          end),
         student_course
```

Oh, that puts Mathematics first.  Personal bias.

Comment: I have tried your answer and it works i put mathematics to 8 and gym to and return ELSE 0. It works but can you tell me, is this right for what i did like defining positions?
Can you please tell me where should i learn this Case statement, this is new for me..

Comment: @LinneaAnderson . . . `case` **expression**:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html.

Comment: @Linnea Anderson I think you understand what case is, but you do not understand procedure of order. It is like creating new column for sort only. You added 8 value for `gym` and 0 values for others. Now you order by that new column.

Comment: Honestly speaking when he wrote the query i didn't know we can also sort the rows by the numbers. I was thinking of primary id on that time. I also didn't know the concept of case earlier. I have read some articles and now i have some understanding like we can also manually sort the rows in the results with case statement. I am actually new in SQL. and Thanks for the document it helps!!@GordonLinoff   
@doctorgu